# Java Android Error "too much data for RSA block"

Tags: java, android, encryption, rsa

A have an error in my Android project (RSA encryption/decryption).
The encryption passes OK, but when I trying to decrypt encrypted text, yhere are an error: **"too much data for RSA block"**.

How to solve this problem?

code:

```
public String Decrypt(String text) throws Exception
{
    try{
        Log.i("Crypto.java:Decrypt", text);
        RSAPrivateKey privateKey = (RSAPrivateKey)kp.getPrivate();
        Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("RSA/ECB/NoPadding");
            cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, privateKey);
            byte[] cipherData = cipher.doFinal(text.getBytes());// <----ERROR: too much data for RSA block
            byte[] decryptedBytes = cipher.doFinal(cipherData);
            String decrypted = new String(decryptedBytes);

            Log.i("Decrypted", decrypted);

        return decrypted;
    }catch(Exception e){
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    }
    return null;
}
```

Comment: I no nothing about this library but my guess is the `text` has too many characters; is too long. Can you try shortening it to a small amount just to test?

Comment: @Perception Besides it not being an exact duplicate, that question is pretty hard to understand, and hard to extract an answer from for somebody just starting with asymmetric encryption/decryption.

Comment: No, " Too much data for RSA block fail. What is PKCS#7" doesn't help me :(

Answer (score 3):

Your issue is that you need to encode/decode the ciphertext (just `text` in your code) if you want to transport it using a textual representation (`String` in your case).

Try and look up base 64 encoding on this site, there should be a lot of information about it. Encode after encryption and decode before decryption. You should also specify a specific character encoding for your plaintext.

Finally, you should probably encrypt with a symmetric cipher, and encrypt the symmetric key using RSA. Otherwise you may run out of space within the RSA calculation, because a public key cannot encrypt data larger than its modulus (key size).

Comment: Sorry, had to fix a slightly confusing typo. Hope you don't mind I expanded on your RSA encryption issue at the end.

Comment: Course I don't mind, thanks for the edit. The actual number of bytes is actually lower because the padding is required for the security of RSA.