# ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException : too much data for RSA block

Tags: java, android, rsa

I have some problem with my android application. I am trying to an app related with RSA encryption/decryption.this is my problem:

I can encrypt short sentences clearly, but when i try to decrypt this message to orginal text I give an error ("too much data for RSA block"). And also if I want to encrypt a long sentences i have same error.I had some search for this problem, and found some solution in this sites:

[Site 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2579103/too-much-data-for-rsa-block-fail-what-is-pkcs7)

[Site 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15806145/getting-error-java-lang-arrayindexoutofboundsexception-too-much-data-for-rsa-bl)

[Site 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15024738/java-android-error-too-much-data-for-rsa-block)

But i dont understand anything, these solutions are so complicated.How can i fixed this problem, Can anyone give me a more simple solution? Thank you.

EDİT:
These are the code blocks that i use for this project.

```
public String RSAEncrypt(String plain) throws NoSuchAlgorithmException, NoSuchPaddingException,InvalidKeyException, IllegalBlockSizeException, BadPaddingException, InvalidKeySpecException, UnsupportedEncodingException {

    publicKey = getPublicKey();
    Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("RSA");
    cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, publicKey);
    byte[] cipherData = cipher.doFinal(plain.getBytes());
    return Base64.encodeToString(cipherData, Base64.DEFAULT);
}

public String RSADecrypt(byte[] encryptedBytes) throws NoSuchAlgorithmException, NoSuchPaddingException,InvalidKeyException, IllegalBlockSizeException, BadPaddingException, InvalidKeySpecException, UnsupportedEncodingException {

    privateKey = getPrivateKey();
    Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("RSA");
    cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, privateKey);      
    byte[] cipherData = cipher.doFinal(encryptedBytes);
    return Base64.encodeToString(cipherData, Base64.DEFAULT);
}
```

Comment: This answer can maybe help you: http://stackoverflow.com/a/16547038/2198638

Comment: Ok. I understand that i am on wrong way. I have to change my cyrpto method.Thanks for your help .

Comment: But am wondiring that.I can encrypt "BAHADIR" but when i want to decrypt it gives same error.I think "BAHADIR" in not a long sentences.

Comment: What is your getPublicKey() method?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

RSA can only encrypt messages that are several bytes shorter than the modulus of the key pair. The extra bytes are for padding, and the exact number depends on the padding scheme you are using.

RSA is for key transport, not data encryption. If you have a long message, encrypt it with AES, using a random key. Then encrypt the AES key with RSA, using the public key of the message recipient. You should be using the `Cipher` class's `wrap()` and `unwrap()` methods.

This is how PGP, S/MIME, TLS (roughly), and any other correctly designed RSA encryption schemes work.

Answer (score -1):

In my use case, I need to encrypt some request data to server, from my app.

If I encrypt the AES key with RSA, that's kind of meaningless because the point of using RSA instead of AES, is to prevent reverse-engineering to get the AES key (versus RSA needs a private key stored in server for decryption). Since the AES key needs to be stored in the app locally, I cannot use the approach as suggested by erickson.

Instead, I split the long string into `List<String>` (Each length suggested by server provider); and encrypt each String.

After that, the `List<String>` is passed to server in a json array, and let server decrypt each and re-join them.

Of course, this approach needs your server's support, and can potentially has performance issue.

Comment: You should generate a new AES key each time the app sends data to the server. Encrypt that key with the RSA key.