# Unable to do encrypt and decrypt with RSA-OAEP in java

Tags: java, encryption, cryptography, rsa, public-key-encryption

I am able to generate key pair and encryption & decryption with 4 characters of string for the below statement

```
 byte[] input = "userid".getBytes();
```

But when I am increasing the string length like below, I am getting exception

```
byte[] input = "userid:789".getBytes();
```

**Code:**

```
import java.security.Key;
import java.security.KeyPair;
import java.security.KeyPairGenerator;
import java.security.SecureRandom;
import java.security.Security;

import javax.crypto.Cipher;

public class RSAOAEP {
  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    Security.addProvider(new org.bouncycastle.jce.provider.BouncyCastleProvider());

    byte[] input = "userid:789".getBytes();
    Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("RSA/None/OAEPWithSHA1AndMGF1Padding", "BC");
    SecureRandom random = new SecureRandom();
    KeyPairGenerator generator = KeyPairGenerator.getInstance("RSA", "BC");

    generator.initialize(386, random);

    KeyPair pair = generator.generateKeyPair();
    Key pubKey = pair.getPublic();

    Key privKey = pair.getPrivate();

    System.out.println("privateKey: "+privKey);
    System.out.println("publicKey: "+pubKey);

    cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, pubKey, random);
    byte[] cipherText = cipher.doFinal(input);
    System.out.println("cipher: " + new String(cipherText));

    cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, privKey);
    byte[] plainText = cipher.doFinal(cipherText);
    System.out.println("plain : " + new String(plainText));
  }
}
```

**Exception:**

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException:
>   too much data for RSA block   at
>   org.bouncycastle.jcajce.provider.asymmetric.rsa.CipherSpi.engineDoFinal(Unknown
>   Source)   at javax.crypto.Cipher.doFinal(Cipher.java:2165)    at
>   RSAOAEP.main(RSAOAEP.java:29)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException : too much data for RSA block](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17811009/arrayindexoutofboundsexception-too-much-data-for-rsa-block)

Comment: **386 bits is _way_ too small for RSA**; it is even below 512 which was chosen for SSL 'export' suites 25 years ago because it was already breakable then. For OAEP using SHA1 it allows only 50 bits = 6 bytes of plaintext, as you have discovered, which isn't even enough for a symmetric key for hybrid encryption (as Nicky suggests) which is conventional and usually better. See dozens of Qs on crypto.SX and security.SX about what key sizes are needed for security, or just go to https://www.keylength.com

Comment: I have increased key size, now I am not getting issue. Thanks James and dave